# Loop through dictionary to match dictionary key to a list of values and append dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, merge, python-requests, biopython

I have two dictionaries (dict_a and dict_b) created using biopython to parse my fasta file. If dict_a keys (which are gene names) are found in dict_b keys, I want to append dict_a with the values from the matching keys (gene names) from dict_b (not all keys from dict_a are in dict_b).

So far, I have created my two dictionaries and a list of the gene names from dict_a keys (list_a).

**I need to append dict_a with the values of dict_b if the key from dict_a exists in dict_b.** I need help with looping through dict_b to find matches to the dict_a keys (that I put in list_a) and then appending dict_a.

Thank you in advance for your help! Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

```
dict_a = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(dict_a_path, "fasta"))
dict_b = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(dict_b_path, "fasta"))

list_a = list(dict_a.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to append `dict_a` with the values of `dict_b` if the key from `dict_a` exists in `dict_b`.

You can iterate over the keys of a `dict` and check if a key is in another `dict` simply with `for` and `in` respectively:

```
for key in dict_a:
    if key in dict_b:
        dict_a[key].append(dict_b[key])
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out but it isn't working. I am getting an error message "AttributeError: 'SeqRecord' object has no attribute 'append'". I think this is because my dictionaries were created from fasta files using biopython.

Comment: @jws unfortunately, I do not know biopython and cannot help you any further. Reading the documentation, it does not seem you can mutate a seqRecord, but I may very well be mistaking.

Comment: thank you for your help! I think I used dict_a[key].append.features(dict_b[key]) which merged the dictionaries and i wrote them out to a file, I am just figure out how to split the lines now. Thanks again!

Comment: @jws Glad you could solve your problem. I encourage you to post what fixed it as an answer to your own question. This may very well be useful to someone else in the future